# Button Doesn't Coordinate As Supposed

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

So I got two buttons on this state [Click here to see the screenshot](http://img194.imageshack.us/img194/2288/s0o0.jpg)

And what is actually happening is that my second button "Start", doesn't work with this values:

```
backButton.renderImage(g, CONTAINER_CENTER_X - backButton.getWidth() - 10, CONTAINER_MAX_Y - backButton.getHeight() - 30);
startButton.renderImage(g, CONTAINER_CENTER_X + 10, CONTAINER_MAX_Y - startButton.getHeight() - 30);
```

Here is output of button coordinates and values I set for x and y:

> BACK BUTTON: [x=245, y= 535, width= 145, height=35] / CURRENT X: 245 /
>   CURRENT Y: 535 START BUTTON: [x=410, y= 535, width= 0, height=35] /
>   CURRENT X: 410 / CURRENT Y: 535

Then I found out, that by adding and subtracting button.getWidth(), I get the button to work

```
backButton.renderImage(g, CONTAINER_CENTER_X - backButton.getWidth() - 10, CONTAINER_MAX_Y - backButton.getHeight() - 30);
startButton.renderImage(g, CONTAINER_CENTER_X  + startButton.getWidth() - startButton.getWidth() + 10, CONTAINER_MAX_Y - startButton.getHeight() - 30);
```

which is pretty strange, and is very ugly... :D

Here is output of button coordinates and values I set for x and y:

> BACK BUTTON: [x=245, y= 535, width= 145, height=35] / CURRENT X: 245 /
>   CURRENT Y: 535
>       START BUTTON: [x=410, y= 535, width= 145, height=35] / CURRENT X: 410 / CURRENT Y: 535

So, check this state code and button class, and tell me what do you think?

ThisState

```
package poker;

import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.Image;
import org.newdawn.slick.Input;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.BasicGameState;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.transition.FadeInTransition;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.transition.FadeOutTransition;
import poker.gui.PButton;
import poker.gui.UIConstants;
import static poker.gui.UIConstants.CONTAINER_CENTER_X;
import static poker.gui.UIConstants.CONTAINER_MAX_Y;
import poker.util.RandomUtility;

public class SetupScreenState extends BasicGameState implements UIConstants, StatePanelInterface {

    public static final int ID = 2;
    private Image titleImage;
    private PButton backButton;
    private PButton startButton;

    public SetupScreenState() {
    }

    @Override
    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    @Override
    public void init(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame game) throws SlickException {
        titleImage = new Image("res/gui/title_setup.png");

        backButton = new PButton("res/gui/button_back.png", "res/gui/button_back_hover.png");
        startButton = new PButton("res/gui/button_start.png", "res/gui/button_start_hover.png");
    } 

    @Override
    public void render(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame game, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
        RandomUtility.bgTheme(container, g);

        renderTopPanel(container, game, g);
        renderCenterPanel(container, game, g);
        renderBottomPanel(container, game, g);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame game, int delta) throws SlickException {
        Input input = container.getInput();
        int mx = input.getMouseX();
        int my = input.getMouseY();

        if (backButton.contains(mx, my)) {
            if (backButton.isButtonPressed(input)) {
                game.enterState(StartScreenState.ID, new FadeOutTransition(), new FadeInTransition());
            }
        } else if (startButton.contains(mx, my)) {
            if (startButton.isButtonPressed(input)) {
                game.enterState(PlayScreenState.ID, new FadeOutTransition(), new FadeInTransition());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void renderTopPanel(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame game, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
        g.drawImage(titleImage, 50, 50);
    }

    @Override
    public void renderCenterPanel(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame game, Graphics g) throws SlickException {

    }

    @Override
    public void renderBottomPanel(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame game, Graphics g) throws SlickException { 
        backButton.renderImage(g, CONTAINER_CENTER_X - backButton.getWidth() - 10, CONTAINER_MAX_Y - backButton.getHeight() - 30);
        startButton.renderImage(g, CONTAINER_CENTER_X  + startButton.getWidth() - startButton.getWidth() + 10, CONTAINER_MAX_Y - startButton.getHeight() - 30);
    }

}
```

BUTTON CLASS

```
package poker.gui;

import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.Image;
import org.newdawn.slick.Input;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;

public class PButton {

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int width;
    private int height;

    private Image image;
    private String classicImage;
    private String hoverImage;

    public PButton() {
    }

    public PButton(String classicImage, String hoverImage) throws SlickException {
        this.classicImage = classicImage;
        this.hoverImage = hoverImage;

        image = new Image(classicImage);
    }

    public PButton(String classicImage, String hoverImage, int x, int y) throws SlickException {
        this.classicImage = classicImage;
        this.hoverImage = hoverImage;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

        image = new Image(classicImage);
    }

    public void renderImage(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(image, x, y);
    }

    public void renderImage(Graphics g, int x, int y) throws SlickException {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

        g.drawImage(image, x, y);
    }

    public boolean contains(int x, int y) throws SlickException {
        int minX = this.x;
        int minY = this.y;
        int maxX = this.x + this.width;
        int maxY = this.y + this.height;

        if ((x > minX && x < maxX) && (y > minY && y < maxY)) {
            if (hoverImage != null) {
                image = new Image(hoverImage);
            }
            return true;
        }
        image = new Image(classicImage);
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isButtonPressed(Input input) throws SlickException {
        return input.isMouseButtonDown(Input.MOUSE_LEFT_BUTTON);
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void setWidth(int width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width = image.getWidth();
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height = image.getHeight();
    }

    public Image getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(Image image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[x=" + x + ", y= " + y + ", width= " + width + ", height=" + height + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: please try to limit the code you show to what you actually think might be relevant. Looking at your output, you're saying that the button works as expected when it has width=0?

Comment: "Be specific

If you ask a vague question, you’ll get a vague answer. But if you give us details and context, we can provide a useful, relevant answer." I'm really sorry, but I thought that's how much information i have to provide, so..

Comment: It looks like you don't initialize your button properly. You have two width fields, image.width and width; the later is never initialized. That's at least one problem...

Comment: @bcr Yea, that button output with widht=0 should go above.. my bad

Comment: How you mean I have two width fields, well I'm assigning that image.width to this.width varibale

Comment: Why the [tag:swing] and [tag:jbutton] tags? What does your question have to do with using the Java Swing GUI library? I looked but don't see any Swing-type code above. Misleading tags can lead to misleading answers and/or frustrated helpers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't initialize the width fields properly.

In `contains()`, you use `this.width`, but it has not been initialized (or precisely it has been default initialized to 0 because it is an instance variable).

When you call `getWidth()`, `width` initializes because `return width = image.getWidth();` assigns `this.width = image.getWidth()`, which explains why you have to call `getWidth()` to get your button to work.

Make sure you initialize your button fields properly. For example, when you create the button (i.e. in the constructor), you should set width to `image.getWidth()`

Comment: Should I that initialize, like this: int maxX = this.x + this.image.getWidth();

Comment: Well yea, this actually fixed problem, this.x + this.image.getWidth(), but do you think it is good idea or that's it ? Thanks for help, I will give you rep.

Comment: personally, I don't see why you have two width fields. If you think that width and image width should be different, then you should allow the user to specify the size of the button as a parameter passed to the constructor. If that is the case, your `getWidth()` should return `width`, not `width = image.getWidth()`, as that will undesirably reassign width. If you think image width and `width` should be the same, you need not keep `this.width` and can just use `image.getWidth()` wherever you have `this.width`